# can i overclock my raspberry pi without a heatsink?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I was tired of waiting for the raspberry to load so I thought why not overclock it? I searched up if it's safe to overclock the pi and I saw that you needed a heatsink but I don't have one. Is it safe to overclock without a heatsink?

Comment: Belongs on [raspberrypi.stackexchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google first , in this link you can read much about safety of overclocking (was 1. link in google) also stackoverflow is more for coding errors as for general questions

http://www.raspberrypi.org/introducing-turbo-mode-up-to-50-more-performance-for-free/

important part :

> We’ve been doing a lot of work to understand the impact of voltage and
>   temperature on lifetime, and are now able to offer a “turbo mode”,
>   which dynamically enables overclock and overvolt under the control of
>   a cpufreq driver, without affecting your warranty. We are happy that
>   the combination of only applying turbo when busy, and limiting turbo
>   when the BCM2835’s internal temperature reaches 85°C, means there will
>   be no measurable reduction in the lifetime of your Raspberry Pi.

so at 85°c it will downclock for safety

Answer (score 1):

I run a rasberry pi b and as far as overclocking without a heatsink or fan I would only recommend going up to 900 to 950 mhz and keep a eye on the temp better safe then sorry. I overclocked mine without a fan or sink and got around 950mhz 500mhz core 500 mhz sdram 6v overvolt and was running around 51 to 55 degrees Celsius way to hot for my taste anything in the 50s worries me from past pc overclocking experience. I made and  I installed a custom heatsink from some laptop parts i had  and put additional vent and air holes in the plastic pi case that came in a cana kit then took a 31/2 cooling fan and mounted and sealed it ontop of the pi case and ran a independent usb power cable to it so I would not over draw from my main power source or from the p I am running 1150 mhz  proc 550 core 550 sdram 8 volt overdraw at a temp around 41 to 45degrees Celsius. Cant clock my ram at 600mhz gets unstable any tips would be nice.

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions - this isn't related to programming.